# I can't see clickable icons under "Your Projects" in my Wamp localhost dashboard

Tags: wamp, project

I have installed a fresh version of WAMP (Version 3.2.0 - 64bit), and on my localhost page under "Your Projects" category I see only names of projects, but it is not clickable (no yellow directory icons) as you can see in the picture.

[image]It suggests me to create a new virtual host for each project, I have never done such a thing in the previous versions. I already have default virtual host "Localhost" and it works fine when I type the path into the browser, the only problem is I can't start or search through my project via dashboard because there are no clickable icons. By the way, I have created a virtual host and the problem with the folder's icons remains.

Answer (score 4):

Open the `index.php` file in the `www` folder and search for the variable
`$projectContents`, around line 346 change the same in the image:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Open the index like how Isaias said before: change on line: 359

$projectContents .= '<li>'.$file.'</li>';

TO

$projectContents .= "<li><a href="'.$file.'" target="_blank">'.$file.'</a></li>';

I also add the target so I keep always the localhost menu... so he open all links in new tab ;) ty

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use images for information that is easily communicated in text. Images are not friendly to search or copy & paste or visually impaired people.